# Spring Cloud Function With Kinesis

Tags: java, spring, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-function

I am trying to listen to data coming in AWS Kinesis Streams, through my AWS Lambda with Spring Cloud Function. I am not able to map the input coming from Kinesis to my Handler.

> MyHandler.java

```
public class RequestHandler extends SpringBootKinesisEventHandler<Payload, List<ABC>> {
}
```

> Mapper function

```
@Bean
public Function<List<Payload>, Void> abc() {
    return value -> {
        value.forEach(payload ->abc.abc(payload.getAbcs()) );
        return null;
    };
```

Here `Payload` is my own POJO.

Any Help will be useful.

Comment: Your question is quite vague as you're not providing any details to the problem you are experiencing (errors, exceptions, logs etc) or sample that reproduces the problem that one of us can look. So, I suggest look at [this test](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/master/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/adapter/aws/SpringBootKinesisEventHandlerTests.java). That should give you a good starting point. . .